# Why mode switch b/w user and kernel is required in OS?

Tags: operating-system

OS has 2 modes i.e user and kernel mode.What is the need of these two modes to protect PCB?

Comment: If everything ran in one level, userspace programs might overwrite the kernel, just like in good old DOS times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good read on the differences:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode/

Basically, you want to keep user mode code from doing anything that could harm the computer ("harm" being defined as overwriting memory other processes are using, sending malicious/dangerous input to hardware, etc). But at the same time, you need to have access to these functions of the computer (i.e, you want your program to be able to open / read / write to files, etc) By segregating these functions to another program that runs in kernel mode (the "kernel" of your OS), you can do this.